# Пушать id: {name, pass } в обьект Users?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Как сделать push в обьект где name, pass пушается в users: [1231334: {name: 'Den', pass: '23dcg4'}]
где 1231334 - now.Date()тоесть id юзера

```html
<div id="creating">
        <input v-model="title" type="text" id="name" required>
        <label for="name">Name</label>

        <textarea v-model="pass" id="pass"></textarea>
        <label for="pass">Description</label>
         <button @click="submitHandler">Create!</button>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Руководство Vue](https://ru.vuejs.org/) вам в помощь и пример

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    newUser: {},
    users: []
  },
  methods: {
    submitHandler() {
      this.users.push({
        [Date.now()]: {
          ...this.newUser
        }
      });
      this.users.reverse()
      this.newUser = {}
    }
  }
})
```

```css
#app {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

#creating {
  display: flex;
  width: 30%;
  padding: 10px;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: #eee;
}

#creating>div {
  margin: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#creating>div>* {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div id="creating">
    <div>
      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input v-model="newUser.title" type="text" id="name" required>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="pass">Description</label>
      <textarea v-model="newUser.pass" id="pass"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button @click="submitHandler">Create!</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <pre>{{ users }}</pre>
  </div>
</div>
```